# Consequences of avoiding PyQt Program Crash on Exit by using sip.setdestroyonexit(False)?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, destructor

I have a `PyQt4` program which tend to crash on exit. I have tried forcing exit of  `QtGui.QMainWindow` by using

```
def closeEvent(self, event):
    exit()
```

But it didn't stop the program from crashing. I also tried to use the

```
app.setActiveWindow(MainWindow)    
exit(app.exec_())
```

But didn't seems to fix the problem. Finally, I found out a SO post mentioned about the similar probelm which is fixed by setting `sip.setdestroyonexit()` to `False`.

> Reference
>
> When the Python interpreter exits PyQt4 (by default) calls the C++
>   destructor of all wrapped instances that it owns. This happens in a
>   random order and can therefore cause the interpreter to crash. This
>   behavior can be disabled by calling the sip.setdestroyonexit()
>   function.
>
> PyQt5 always calls sip.setdestroyonexit() automatically.

I managed to prevent my program from crashing by setting this setting to `False`.
Now, I am wondering will there be any consequences of setting `sip.setdestroyonexit()` to `False`? What will happen if I disable the calls to C++ destructors?

Comment: You could start programming your app again from scratch and see exactly at which newly inserted line the crashes start to occur. Maybe you forgot to do something important. Depending on what is was it might result in something bad or not. Without knowing the cause you cannot know. Maybe it's just a bug in PyQt. I would try to create a minimal example for the crashes and post it here.

Comment: I don't feel confident enough to provide an answer, but since no one else has said anything, I'll throw in my 2c. I would say that the only consequences will be if a particular Qt class closes/cleans up something important during destruction. One thing that might do this would be Qt Networking classes (I'm guessing they maybe close connections?). It may or may not be a big deal. My suggestion would be to explicitly cleanup/destruct any Qt objects on close (maybe hook into `aboutToQuit()`?) that you are concerned might have a problem. I should think anything derived from QWidget is fine though!

Comment: @three_pineapples I guess I should be fine as everything in my code is mostly derived from `QWidget` and there are no Qt Networking classes.

Comment: @Trilarion re-writing the whole app is simply not a choice as I have several thousands lines of codes. I tried to comment out the parts of program, but it seems like no matter which part I remove, unless I have just a empty `QMainWindow`, it will still crash sometimes upon exit(not every time).

Comment: @ChrisAung In case you used a versioning system you could go back to the last crash-free version and continue from there step by step. For a project of this size a local Git might really be helpful.